# "At day five", "on day five", or something else?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, time

When considering a set of days and writing about them in a 'diary mode', what preposition should I use in the following example:

> - He died at day 5 of the treatment.
> - He died on day 5 of the treatment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"On" works better here. It implies that he died at some point on the 5th day of the treatment. I would use "at" to reference a very specific point in time (rather than a relatively longer period of time, such as a day), for example: "He died *on* the 5th day of the treatment *at* 3:02 PM".

See also: http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm

Comment: Thanks! I thought the same, but wasn't 100% secure :)

Comment: Perfect! You should delete "I think". +1